# odoo, qweb: I like to replace attribute's value in odoo report

Tags: qweb, odoo-13

In odoo, qweb report. I have created an inherited report whith objective to change t-call attribute value from internal_layout to external layout. i have used the next code:

```html
<template id="!!!!!!!!!!!!"  inherit_id="!!!!!!!!!!!!!">
            <xpath expr="//t[@t-call='web.internal_layout']"  position="attributes">
                <attribute name="attrs">{'t-call':'web.external_layout'}</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </template>
```

This code did not work, I wonder if there is a way to insert sub part of the same report.

```html
<template id="!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"  inherit_id="!!!!!!!!!!!">
            <xpath expr="//t[@t-call='web.internal_layout']"  position="replace">
                <t t-call='web.external_layout'>
                    insert here original sub report
                 </t>
            </xpath>
        </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Operation doable by this small changment !

```html
<data>
<template id="!!!!!!!!!!"  inherit_id="!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!">
            <xpath expr="//t[@t-call='web.internal_layout']"  position="attributes">
                <attribute name="t-call">web.external_layout</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </template>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your views is for multiple object, like contains:

`<t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context({'lang':o.customer_id.lang})" />`

you must add others attributes modification:

```
<xpath expr="//t[@t-call='web.internal_layout']"  position="attributes">
     <attribute name="t-call">web.external_layout</attribute>
     <attribute name="t-foreach">docs</attribute>
     <attribute name="t-as">o</attribute>
</xpath>
```